# How to register a Gradle task after configurations have been resolved?

Tags: java, gradle, gradle-plugin

I have several jars with test classes in the private Maven repository. As shown below, these jars are imported by a customized configuration `testJar`.

```
dependencies {
    testJar "com.example:test1:1.0"
    testJar "com.example:test2:1.0"
}
```

I want to run these tests in separate Gradle test tasks. i.e.

- Execute tests in test-1.jar with task `test1`.
- Execute tests in test-2.jar with task `test2`.

> Why not execute these tests in the same task?
> The tests in different jars may affect each other.

To achieve this, I should register tasks `test1` and `test2` after the configuration `testJar` is resolved.

Comment: Add details as to what the task is supposed to do and what do you mean by “according to the resolved artifacts”.

Answer (score 0):

You can create additional Gradle test tasks named `test*`, and use the include and exclude properties to configure which task runs what subset of tests. The jar has absolutely nothing to do with running tests, because Gradle doesn’t know what tests are in it. The tests are discovered at runtime by the appropriate test engine (like JUnit 5).